# Anki does not play audio and show error "Sound and video on cards will not function until mpv or mplayer is installed."

Tags: 20.04, anki

Anki does not play audio and show error "Sound and video on cards will not function until mpv or mplayer is installed."

How can I fix it?

mpv and mplayer are installed
ubuntu 20.04

Anki version is 2.1.15 (442df9d6)

Comment: Just restarting the app fixed this for me.  (Have used Anki with audios for a long time, no issues, started seeing this today out of nowhere.)

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `mplayer` in your computer using these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mplayer mplayer-gui
```

After that restart your Anki. It worked for me.

[Source for installing mplayer manually](https://itsfoss.com/mplayer/)

Comment: `mplayer-gui` isn't necessary

Comment: Nice! this working on Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS Thank you! (2024)

Answer (score 3):

mpv didn't work for me and mplayer-gui isn't needed. I'm on ubuntu focal 20.04 and all that was needed is

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mplayer
```

After that restart anki and it worked

The anki version is the version for ubuntu 20.04 which is 2.1.15 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/anki

Answer (score 1):

Change the line 107 in your file `/usr/share/anki/anki/mpv.py` from

```python
        self.argv += ["--input-ipc-server", self._sock_filename]
```

to

```python
        self.argv += ["--input-ipc-server=" + self._sock_filename]
```

as in the fixed [upstream](https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/af911aa66992d08278b4bca61be7e4ae5ce7c3fa/qt/aqt/mpv.py#L122).

You'd better add the file `/usr/share/anki/anki/mpv.py` to local diversions lest it be overwritten by any unfixed "update".  If you don't know what local diversion is, just `man dpkg-divert`.

```
dpkg-divert  --divert /usr/share/anki/anki/mpv.py~ --no-rename --add /usr/share/anki/anki/mpv.py
```